# How to create two consecutive Group By in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, count

I have this kind of code

```
SELECT MONTH(date_entered) AS Month,sex, COUNT(*) AS Customer
  FROM customer
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY Month
```

I want to split `sex (M and F)` for each month. But the result that I get combine both sex

[image: The sex and customer is wrong]

Comment: Just `GROUP BY Month, sex`

Comment: *I want to split sex (M and F) for each month.* Show DESIRED output. Does you need additional column "total" to each separate row shown above, or you need only `month, total` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `sex` in `group by` as well

```
SELECT 
    MONTH(date_entered) AS Month,
    sex, 
    COUNT(*) AS Customer
FROM customer
GROUP BY
    MONTH(date_entered),
    sex
ORDER BY 
    Month
```